# $Lu = -u'' + f(x) u$ has a strictly negative eigenvalue

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\, dx = 0$ and $f$ is not identically  0. The problem I am working on is to show that $Lu := -u'' + f(x)u$ with boundary condition $u'(0) = u'(1) = 0$ must have a strictly negative eigenvalue.

The way I'm approaching this problem is as follows. Suppose all eigenvalues are $\geq 0$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue $\geq 0$ and suppose $u$ is a corresponding eigenfunction. Then $$0 \leq \int_{0}^{1}\lambda u^{2}\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}u\cdot Lu\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}u(-u'' + f(x)u)\, dx = \int_{0}^{1}u'^{2} + f(x)u^{2}\, dx$$ where in the last step I have used integration by parts. The issue now is that I don't know how to utilize the condition that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\, dx = 0$, is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got a comment that my answer was not really an answer, I update it. I don't know what tools you have, but here goes.

The smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ is given by
$$
\lambda=\text{min}\int_0^1 (u')^2+f u^2\,dx
$$
where the minimum is taken over all $u$ in the domain with $\int_0^1 u^2\,dx=1$. Let $u(x)=1$, and calculate the integral (here you use the property $\int_0^1 f\,dx=0$). Also use the fact that $u(x)=1$ is not an eigenfunction.

I hope this is now considered as an answer...

Comment: @Tomás I changed the answer now with some more details...

Comment: How does $u(x) = 1$ not being an eigenfunction show that $L$ must have a strictly negative eigenvalue?

Comment: The minimum is attained for the eigenfunction corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue only. Since we provide a function $u$ that is not an eigenfunction, but giving integral zero, there must exist a function (the eigenfunction!) such that the integral is less than zero. Hence the eigenvalue is less than zero.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks, I have another question: Why can we guarantee that a smallest eigenvalue exists? Also when you take the minimum, why is your domain $\int_{0}^{1}u^{2}\, dx = 1$ rather than $u'(0) = u'(1) = 0$?

Comment: Let us assume that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (you write that $f$ is continuous, but not where). Then $f$ attains a minimal value, say $f_m$. But then $\text{min}\int_0^1 (u')^2+fu^2\,dx\geq \int_0^1 (u')^2+f_m u^2\,dx\geq f_m\int_0^1 u^2\,dx$ which implies that the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda\geq f_m$. About the domain: I mean that $u$ is in the domain if it is square integrable and $\int_0^1 (u')^2+fu^2\,dx<+\infty$. This fits well with the Neumann boundary conditions $u'(0)=0$ and $u'(1)=0$. Things for you to look up: form domain, existence of eigenvalues, Sturm-Liouville theory.